# Images not properly aligned for carousel in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Images are not properly aligning in the center of the page. Instead it is aligning at the left of the page. Also, images are of various sizes. So, how to make it fix to one specific size and make it responsive. Please check the below code for the same -

```css
#carousel-custom {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators {
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: auto;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li img {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li.active img {
    opacity: 1;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li:hover img {
    opacity: 0.75;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-outer {
    position: relative;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div id="myPicture" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
       <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target = "#myPicture" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target = "#myPicture" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
          <li data-target = "#myPicture" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
       </ol>
       <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/250x350" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/300x350" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x350" alt="test"  class="img-responsive">    
          </div>
       </div>
      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myPicture" data-slide="prev"><span class ="icon-prev"></span></a>
   <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myPicture" data-slide="next"><span class ="icon-next"></span></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a Plunker example so I can see your issue. I am not able to reproduce your error. Have you tried to wrap this in a container and row?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by removing these `style="max-height:1400px;max-width:900px"`

```css
#carousel-custom {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators {
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: auto;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li img {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li.active img {
    opacity: 1;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li:hover img {
    opacity: 0.75;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-outer {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myPicture" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myPicture" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myPicture" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myPicture" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2350x1150/000" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2350x1150/f00" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2350x1150/000" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div> <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myPicture" data-slide="prev"><span class ="icon-prev"></span></a>
 <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myPicture" data-slide="next"><span class ="icon-next"></span></a>

</div>
```

Comment: I have made changes as mentioned by you. Also, images are of various sizes. How to make image sizes similar for all the images ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your css for center align images

```
#carousel-custom .carousel-inner > .item > a > img, 
#carousel-custom .carousel-inner > .item > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also the id of carousel wrapper is myPicture changed this to carousel-custom as it is used in css

You have passed different size images in img src tag.

```css
#carousel-custom {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-inner > .item > a > img, 
#carousel-custom .carousel-inner > .item > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators {
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: auto;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li img {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li.active img {
    opacity: 1;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li:hover img {
    opacity: 0.75;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-outer {
    position: relative;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div id="carousel-custom" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
       <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target = "#carousel-custom" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target = "#carousel-custom" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
          <li data-target = "#carousel-custom" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
       </ol>
       <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/300x350" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/300x350" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x350" alt="test"  class="img-responsive">    
          </div>
       </div>
      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel-custom" data-slide="prev"><span class ="icon-prev"></span></a>
   <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel-custom" data-slide="next"><span class ="icon-next"></span></a>
  </div>
```